# How can I get the Inner Html of an Iframe with puppeteer using headless chrome?

Tags: iframe, automation, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to access the .contentWindow.document of an Iframe (specifically the Ad served via google on a page).

If you perform this in the console via chrome, it comes back as expected. For example,

```
var t = document.getElementById('google_ads_iframe_175840252/90-min/Homepage/Index/Top_0').contentWindow.document;

window.onload=t
```

When performing the same via puppeteer with headless chrome, a funky Json with attributes for the iframe is returned. For example:

```
{ title:
   { location:
      { replace: {},
        assign: {},
        href: 'https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/safeframe/1-0-27/html/container.html',
        ancestorOrigins: [Object],
        origin: 'https://tpc.googlesyndication.com',
        protocol: 'https:',
        host: 'tpc.googlesyndication.com',
        hostname: 'tpc.googlesyndication.com',
        port: '',
        pathname: '/safeframe/1-0-27/html/container.html',
        search: '',
        hash: '',
        reload: {},
        toString: {} },
     closure_lm_292767: null,
     '4CGeArbVQ': 100 } }
```

I am pretty new to puppeteer, any advice is helpful, I will include my puppeteer code below.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
let scrape = async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: [
      '--start-maximized','--disable-web-security',
          ],
        headless: false,
        //slowMo: 600,
        userDataDir: 'test-profile-dir',

        });

    const page = await browser.newPage();


try {
    await page.setViewport({width: 1920, height: 1080});
    await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36');
    await page.goto('https://www.90min.com/');
    await page.waitFor(2000);
} catch(error) {
    console.error(error);
}



try {
    const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
    let title = document.getElementById('google_ads_iframe_175840252/90-min/Homepage/Index/Top_0').contentWindow.document;
    window.onload= title;
    return {
     title
           }
    });


    browser.close();
    return result;
} catch(error) {
    console.error(error);
}
};

    scrape().then((value) => {
    console.log(value); // Success!
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer, using .contentWindow.document.childNodes["0"].innerHTML; in puppeteer will bring back the juicy iframe contents.